# Rails 5 returning `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I am new to trying to understand associations in ActiveRecord and it is currently returning `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` to a query I am running in the Web Console.

In a nutshell, I read the Rails Guides and figured `has_and_belongs_to_many` was the best solution. My terminal shows it is running the query but it appears to just be returning an empty array and the output is below.

`Processing by ScheduleController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Schedule Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "schedules".* FROM "schedules" WHERE "schedules"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."team" = ?  [["team", "@schedule.home"]]`

I have a `Schedule` and a `Players` model, the idea is to return a list of players based on home and away team names.

models/player.rb

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :schedules
end
```

models/schedule.rb

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end
```

db/migrate/(numbers)_create_schedules.rb

```
class CreateSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :schedules do |t|
      t.string :leagueGame
      t.string :home
      t.string :homeAbr
      t.string :away
      t.string :awayAbr
      t.string :venue
      t.string :prettyDate
      t.string :homeLogo
      t.string :homeLogoLarge
      t.string :awayLogo
      t.string :awayLogoLarge
      t.date :date

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :player_schedule do |t|
      t.belongs_to :player, index: true
      t.belongs_to :schedule, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/(numbers)_create_players.rb

```
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :team
      t.string :shoots
      t.string :catches
      t.string :position
      t.string :abr
      t.integer :number
      t.integer :gp
      t.integer :goals
      t.integer :assists
      t.integer :points
      t.integer :pim
      t.integer :plusMinus
      t.decimal :gaa
      t.integer :svs

      t.timestamps
    end   
  end
end
```

controllers/schedule_controller.rb

```
# For brevity
  def show
    @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
    @home_lineup = Player.where(team: '@schedule.home')
  end
```

The `@home_lineup` is the call returning the empty array. I can call `@schedule.home` and it displays the correct team name but am I able to call it like I have as part of a table lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@home_lineup = Player.where(team: '@schedule.home')
```

with

```
@home_lineup = Player.where(team: @schedule.home)
```

As per your code, you are searching for team with name '@schedule.home' instead of the actual team name.

Comment: My syntax is always slightly wrong and the answer is always so simple!

Thank you so much @Sajin :)

Comment: @RedHendery If the answer is correct, please accept it :)